# How to let SKSpriteNode don't rotation texture

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I want to create a metal ball on the screen, I had the material and run animation done. But When the ball was rolling that I hope the texture shouldn't roating. Because that made rolling ball not look like metal ball...

There is anyways or not? I could make SKSpriteNode don't rotate the ball.

```
SKSpriteNode *node = [self spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball.png"];
node.name = @"ball";
node.size = CGSizeMake(sideSize, sideSize);
node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius: sideSize/2];
node.physicsBody.restitution = 0.2;
node.physicsBody.friction = 0.01;
node.physicsBody.angularDamping = 0.5;
node.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = GMCategoryBall;
node.position = CGPointMake(wood.position.x,wood..position.y +wood..size.height);
node.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask =.....
node.physicsBody.collisionBitMask =.....
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some suggestions:

- Add another `SKSpriteNode` without a `physicsBody` that is just there for looks.  Have it always centered on your ball.
- Add another `SKSpriteNode` as a sub-node of your ball, and set its rotation to the opposite of your ball's rotation.
- Add another `SKSpriteNode`, set its `physicsBody` to a bit mask value that won't interact with anything else in the scene (0 is a good choice) and set a joint that keeps it locked to the ball.  Turn off rotation for that Sprite.